# Can we construct a chain of all elements greater than $a\in S$ in partially ordered set $S$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have a partially ordered set $S$, and an element $a\in S$. Can we construct a (possibly infinite) chain of **all** elements greater than $a$ in $S$?

For example, say we have $\Bbb{N}$. If we take $3\in\Bbb{N}$, we can obviously construct the chain of all elements greater than $3$.

Can we do that in general? Even if we are unaware of the elements in $S$? Can we **assume the existence** of such a chain?

Thanks!

Comment: This is like, your fifth account. How about registering to the site, and merging all your accounts together?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Consider the po-set $S=\{a,b,c,\}$ with $a<b, a<c$ and $b$ and $c$ not comparable. Then the set $\{b,c\}$ of all elements greater than $a$ is not a chain.

In the set of natural numbers, you can do it because it is a totally (linearly) ordered set. Moreover, you can linearly extend the order in my example to make it total (linear).